# Botones en líneas (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

¿Cómo puedo hacer que los botones estén en línea? Ando haciendo un comando de ayuda para mi bot, y salen todos los botones en fila, apilados de arriba para abajo, ¿Me podrían ayudar? Ando tratando de averiguar como hacerlo hace varios meses, no encuentro ningún tutorial xd. Dejaré el código abajo:

````js
        let ayuda = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Comando De Ayuda')
            .setDescription(':Comunidad\n:Diversión\n⚙: Moderación\n:Administración\n:Volver')
            .setColor('RANDOM')

        let moderación = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents([
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('mod')
                .setEmoji('⚙')
                .setStyle('PRIMARY')
                .setLabel('Mods')
            ])
        let comunidad = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents([
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('comu')
                .setEmoji('')
                .setStyle('PRIMARY')
                .setLabel('Comunidad')
            ])
        let administración = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents([
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('admin')
                .setEmoji('⚖')
                .setStyle('PRIMARY')
                .setLabel('Admins')
            ])
        let diversión = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents([
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('div')
                .setEmoji('')
                .setStyle('PRIMARY')
                .setLabel('Diversión')
            ])
        let volver = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents([
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('volver')
                .setEmoji('')
                .setStyle('DANGER')
                .setLabel('Volver')
            ])```
````

Comment: ¿Los botones te aparece en _una columna de varias filas_, tal vez?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto ocurre porque creas los botones en distintos **MessageActionRow**

Crea los botones independientemente y los añades todos a una sóla messageActionRow, que es la que añadirás al mensaje que se enviará con los botones

```js
let ayuda = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Comando De Ayuda')
            .setDescription(':Comunidad\n:Diversión\n⚙: Moderación\n:Administración\n:Volver')
            .setColor('RANDOM');
   
let moderación = new MessageButton()
                 .setCustomId('mod')
                 .setEmoji('⚙')
                 .setStyle('PRIMARY')
                 .setLabel('Mods');

let comunidad = new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('comu')
                .setEmoji('')
                .setStyle('PRIMARY')
                .setLabel('Comunidad');

let administración = new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('admin')
                    .setEmoji('⚖')
                    .setStyle('PRIMARY')
                    .setLabel('Admins');

let diversión = new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('div')
                .setEmoji('')
                .setStyle('PRIMARY')
                .setLabel('Diversión');

let volver = new MessageButton()
             .setCustomId('volver')
             .setEmoji('')
             .setStyle('DANGER')
             .setLabel('Volver');

let messageActionRow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents([moderación, comunidad, administración, diversión, volver]);
```